# Oracle: Single Row Subquery Returns More than One Row

Tags: oracle, subquery, correlated

Based on other questions I believe I need a correlated sub query but I can't quite figure out the syntax. My sub selection creates multiple rows per jobnumber.

```
select distinct projectmaster.projectidentity as PROJECT,
                jdedwards.jobnumber,

                (select cast(substr(overagenarrative, 1, 2000) as
                             varchar(4000 byte))
                   from jlog.approvedjobsoverbudget
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN jlog.jdedwards
                     ON jdedwards.jobnumber =
                        approvedjobsoverbudget.jobnumber) as Overage

  from jlog.jdedwards,
       jlog.projectjobdetail,
       jlog.projectmaster,
       jlog.approvedjobsoverbudget
 where jdedwards.jobnumber = projectjobdetail.jobnumber
   and projectjobdetail.projectidentity = projectmaster.projectidentity
   and jdedwards.budgetyear = projectmaster.budgetyear
   and jlog.projectmaster.Projectstatus in (2)

   and jdedwards.jobnumber = approvedjobsoverbudget.jobnumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply

```
select distinct projectmaster.projectidentity as PROJECT,
                jdedwards.jobnumber,
                --
-- this line ...
                cast(substr(overagenarrative, 1, 2000) as varchar2(4000 byte) as overage
-- ... instead of all this:
--                (select cast(substr(overagenarrative, 1, 2000) as
--                             varchar(4000 byte))
--                   from jlog.approvedjobsoverbudget
--                   LEFT OUTER JOIN jlog.jdedwards
--                     ON jdedwards.jobnumber =
--                        approvedjobsoverbudget.jobnumber) as Overage
  from jlog.jdedwards,
       jlog.projectjobdetail,
       jlog.projectmaster,
       jlog.approvedjobsoverbudget
 where jdedwards.jobnumber = projectjobdetail.jobnumber
   and projectjobdetail.projectidentity = projectmaster.projectidentity
   and jdedwards.budgetyear = projectmaster.budgetyear
   and jlog.projectmaster.Projectstatus in (2)
   and jdedwards.jobnumber = approvedjobsoverbudget.jobnumber
```

Note comments I put into the code.

Comment: I ended up going with this version after a lot of trial and error. Thanks for the feedback. I was trying to create an outer join so that I would get records that did not include a value for OVERAGE.